# Kind product in haskell

Tags: haskell

Can I write a product kind for kind product of kinds without polluting the term level namespace ?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

data Pair a b = Pair a b

type family Proj1 (asd :: Pair a b) where
  Proj1 ('Pair a b) = a

type family Proj2 (asd :: Pair a b) where
  Proj2 ('Pair a b) = b
```

Comment: I would think not, for the same reason you can't keep `Pair` out of the term-level namespace in the first place.

Comment: @chepner I can keep Pair out of my term level namespace : I just don't write it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can leave out the constructor:

```
data Pair a b
```

Now, `Pair` is both a type-level product:

```
x :: Pair a b
x = undefined
```

and a kind-level product:

```
type family Proj1 (x :: Pair a b)
```

with no associated term-level `Pair`.

It ends up being a little hard to do much with it.  Since it's uninhabited as a type (no terms) and uninhabited as a kind (no types).

I think that's what @chepner was pointing out in the comment.  Since the only way to define a new kind in Haskell is to define a new type and lift it, the only way to define a new kind without affecting the term-level namespace is to define an uninhabited new type and lift it to an uninhabited kind.

Note that, as soon as `DataKinds` is enabled, the kind-level product `(,)` automatically springs into existence, so if your worry is about *adding* to term-level namespace pollution, you can just use that one:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family Proj1 (asd :: (a,b)) where
  Proj1 '(a,b) = a

type family Proj2 (asd :: (a,b)) where
  Proj2 '(a,b) = a
```

and in GHCi:

```
> :kind! Proj1 '(Int, String)
Proj1 '(Int,String) :: *
= Int
```

Comment: Does it only exist in recent compiler ? I use 8.10.7 and (,) seems to belong to *

Comment: I've clarified with example code.  Since `(,)` is a term-level constructor for the type-level constructor `(,)` -- just as `Pair` is a term-level constructor for the type-level constructor `Pair` in your example -- `DataKinds` lifts it to a type-level constructor `(,)` for the the kind-level constructor `(,)`.   So, it should work on any version of the compiler that supports `DataKinds` (and `PolyKinds`, for your intended usage).

Comment: ah, of course !  '(,) is lifted as well